# BeautifulSoup - search text inside a tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests
user = UserAgent()
headers = {
    'user-agent' : user.random
}
url = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/?utm_source=domain&utm_campaign=wilberes.ru'
def main():
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    main = soup.find('div', class_='menu-burger__main')
    ul = main.find('ul', class_='menu-burger__main-list')
    all = ul.find_all_next('li', class_='menu-burger__main-list-item')
    f = open('link.txt', 'a')
    for lin in all:
        get_link = lin.find('a').get('href')
        f.write(get_link + '\n')
    f.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm trying to parse a link to a section and its name. I managed to get the link, but how can I get the name if it is not in the tag?

[image: screenshot of a browser with the Dec tools open highlighting an HTML element]

Comment: I wouldn't say the name is not in the tag. It is not a attribute in the tag. It is the "text", "inner text", "content", or "inner html" of the tag (there are various terms used to describe this using in different contexts which make it a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the string property seems to be the correct method based on BS4 documentation:

```
myLink = soup.find('a')
myLinkText = str(myLink.string)
```

The idea of using str() is to convert the text to regular python strings, as `.string` returns a BS4 NavigableString object (you may find you don't really have to do this, though - it might be safer though, as well as stripping whitespace from the string so that you don't get weird newlines or padding with the result -- `str(myLink.string).strip()`)

Reference: https://crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring

In your code, you are actually getting the href, so take note that in my code above I am getting the anchor tag, not just it's href attribute.